# Setting Transport level security on webHttp WCF service

Tags: wcf, security, webhttp

I am trying to set transport level security on a webHttp binding WCF service my current config looks like this

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp"
    contract="PrimeStreamInfoServices.IService1" name="Client" />
</client>
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="webHttp" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000"  maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000"  maxBufferSize="1500000">
  <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"

            proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="string" />
  </security>
  </binding>

</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>

  <service name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" contract="PrimeStreamInfoServices.IService1">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior">

      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<diagnostics>

  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true"  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />

</diagnostics>
```

however when i run my service i get  an exception:
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

I know im missing something, and I have been trying various things I cant figure it out, anyone got some input on what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - switch to HTTPS, with a suitable certificate. Transport security, in the case of HTTP is provided by an SSL channel. You can't have WS* transport security over plain HTTPS

Comment: where do  i specify that i want HTTPs?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my previous answer, I was thinking wsHttpBinding not webHttpBinding.

It is the address that you use to call the service that must start with https.

https://machineName/ServiceName

Comment: Will message encrypt the request during its transport so no packet sniffers can just r ead the plain text?

Comment: It encrypts before it gets sent, so a packet sniffer will not be able to see the contents.

Comment: For a description of message security see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx

Comment: anyway i dont think you can do message for webHttp binding

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add a base address (inside the `<host>` element of your service config) which is https ? Are you adding a (or multiple) base address(es) in code?

```
<service name="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1" 
         behaviorConfiguration="PrimeStreamInfoServices.Service1Behavior">
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8080/YourService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
   </host>
   <!-- Service Endpoints -->
   <endpoint ......
</service>
```

Not 100% sure if that works with the webHttpBinding, but give it a try!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Remember that besides the right WCF config, you also need to configure IIS property to enable SSL on it (including setting the right X.509 certificate for SSL). The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx) have some decent information on how to do it.